# Filter Companies from Address Book References

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Using the 'AddressBook.framework' is it possible to filter out all companies (i.e. just people). For example, how would one modify the following code to remove companies:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef contacts = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressbook);
```

I found that companies do not appear to be stored as groups (they are still returned with the above call). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, companies are records/people in the Address Book.

Look up the value for the `kABPersonFlags` -- one of the flags is "show as company".  Then just do a bitmask and compare.

```
if (([aPerson valueForProperty:kABPersonFlags] & kABShowAsMask) == kABShowAsCompany) {
   // it's a company
} else {
   // it's a person, resource, or room
}
```

I used the following references from Apple, which you should probably read as well:

- [Address Book Programming Guide for Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/Tasks/AccessingData.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001023-BABHHIHC)
- [Address Book Constants Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Miscellaneous/AddressBook_Constants/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003952-CH3g-SW62)
- [ABPerson Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABPerson_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001546-SW1)

---

EDIT: Sorry, the above is for Address Book on Mac OS X.  Try this for iOS:

```
ABRecordRef aRecord = ...  // Assume this exists
CFNumberRef recordType = ABRecordCopyValue(aRecord, kABPersonKindProperty);
if (recordType == kABPersonKindOrganization) {
   // it's a company
} else {
   // it's a person, resource, or room
}
```

The idea is the same: get the value of the person type property, and see what it tells you.

Used these Apple docs:

- [Address Book Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/300-BasicObjects/BasicObjects.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH3-SW1)
- [ABPerson Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007210-CH991-SW37)